# How to get rid of whitespace in my menu

Tags: html, css, menu, whitespace, nav

So I'm making a site for a school project and I want to know how I can remove the whitespace on the sides of the menu when hovering over the first and last links. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=URqPawrqFg).

Sorry if my code is not that great, I'm a beginner...
Also I notice that my menu is staying still but everything else is going crazy with positioning when in different resolutions. How do I get it so everything stays in relatively the same position in different resolutions?

Thanks.

Oh and here's the html:

```
<body>
    <h1 class='titles'>Phosphorus 4 Dummies</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul class='menu'>
            <li id='home'><a href='#'>Home</li></a>
            <li id='phys'><a href='#'>Phys. Prop.</li></a>
            <li id='chem'><a href='#'>Chem. Prop.</li></a>
            <li id='facts'><a href='#'>Fun Facts</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class='info'>Phosphorus is a very reactive element in the Nitrogen Group. It has 15 protons, 16 neutrons, and 5 valence electrons. It is a non-metal so it can be found on the right side of the zig-zag along with other non-metals. Its symbol is a simple P.</p>
    <img src='http://images-of-elements.com/red-phosphorus.jpg' id='redPhosphorus' height=300px />
```

And the css:

```
body {
    margin: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.titles {
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
}

.menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 760px;
    bottom: 330px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.menu li {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    float: none;
}

.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding-right: 11px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu li:nth-child(4) a {
    border: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: please include some of your code in the question (not just a fiddle).

Comment: sorry I'm new here I will be sure to next time.

Comment: Your fiddle is empty :) Your link is broken

Comment: just click the `edit` button and add it, (ctrl + k will format it as code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is whitespace because your `menu` is set at a `width: 760px`, but your menu list does not fit all the way across, so there is white space.

Also, to make it responsive, you need to use media queries.

**UPDATE:**

If you know the expected results [height, width, etc] you have to give your `<nav>` the set **width**, and the `<ul>` to a larger width, but add `overflow: hidden` and `height: 41px`

Here is a [fiddle to experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/R5pBL/) with.  You did not have an ideal layout, but I've worked with what you gave.  If anyone finds a better solution I would be more than happy to observe.

Comment: So how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Just updated my answer with a fiddle and some code.  The thing with my solution is that you have to make sure the font doesn't bleed past the <nav> width, otherwise you won't see it.  It may be problematic as different browsers vary at rendering fonts.

Answer (score 0):

i took a look at your code, you nested the elements wrongly, make sure to close the `a` tag first

```
<li><a></li></a>
```

should be:

```
<li><a></a></li>
```